# Old version of SAS

Tags: version, vms

I am getting funky results in several ways (Like jibberish..almost like when opening a word document the wrong way).  I am told our company is running an old version of SAS.  it runs in a VMS environment.   Can SAS "break down so to speak", where one not only gets jibberish, but basic logic statements fail work in an environment that where the SAS version is outdated, so to speak?  almost as if something has become corrupted.  Not sure if my question makes sense.  I am not a techy person, so I do not know the language of IT very well.  I can only program.    anyway, does anybody have any experience with anything like this?  thanks  John

Comment: You need to be much more specific about what the issue is. Are you talking about SAS code?  If you are running on old version of SAS then newer statements, procs and options will not work.  If you are talking about SAS datasets, then they are not cross platform compatible between VMS and other operating systems. You need to make transport files (PROC CPORT/CIMPORT) to move the datasets.

Comment: yes, I am talking about SAS code.  I guess what seems weird is that it SEEMS to be falling apart one piece at a time.  some if then statements not working SPORADICALLY.  (at least I think).  and in a few cases, getting complete jibberish, but everything else still seems to work as expected.

Comment: Not much we can do to help without re-producible errors.  Perhaps you are having memory/disk issues.  I doubt that SAS is still supporting SAS on VMS.  Who owns Digital now (Dell?) ? Do they still support VMS?